# ShowDialog, PropertyGrid and Timer problem

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, propertygrid, showdialog

I have a strange bug, please, let me know if you have any clues about the reason.

I have a `Timer` (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) on my main form, which fires some updates, which also eventually update the main form UI. Then I have an editor, which is opened from the main form using the `ShowDialog()` method. On this editor I have a `PropertyGrid` (`System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid`).

I am unable to reproduce it everytime, but pretty often, when I use dropdowns on that property grid in editor it gets stuck, that is OK/Cancel buttons don't close the form, property grid becomes not usable, Close button in the form header doesn't work.

There are no exceptions in the background, and if I break the process I see that the app is doing some calculations related to the updates I mentioned in the beginning.

What can you recommend? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this issue?

Comment: @roken: I forgot :-)  I think we used a workaround, like stopping the UI refreshing timers while a modal dialog is active...

Comment: Sad day.  Thanks for the reply, I can't expect you to remember an issue from three years ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the thread timer's Tick method doesn't execute on a different thread, so it's locking everything else until it's done. I made a test winforms app that had a timer and 2 buttons on it whose events did this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmShow show = new frmShow();
    show.ShowDialog(); // frmShow just has some controls on it to fiddle with
}
```

and indeed it blocked as you described. The following solved it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoStuff);
}

private void DoStuff(object something)
{
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, SnOrfus
But it doesn't really look like you describe in my case. The UI thread is not blocked by the caluclations, I can get into the closing handler for my editor form.... I can step it through, but the form just doesn't close after it!..

Comment: Why was this the accepted answer? We have the exact same issue and as you mention in your comment above, this problem is NOT due to the UI thread simply being hung.  The property grid is fully responsive, the button click events are firing, but the form just wont close.